# Tensorflow Federated in C++

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I'm trying to find a way to utilise Tensorflow Federated in C++. I know it's possible to do it for the regular Tensorflow with the Core API, however I can't find a way for Federated. If it's not possible suggestions for workarounds would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful to know which part(s) of TFF you want to use in C++, and what your use case is, as that will influence the answer:

- The APIs for defining federated computations (`tff.federated_computation`); as with TensorFlow, these are pretty tightly coupled to Python.
- Executing serialized computations (stored as instances of `computation.proto`). This can conceptually be done using a purely C++ API, though TFF doesn't currently provide such a runtime.

Answer (score 1):

TFF has since implemented a C++ runtime along the lines of Brendan's answer. TFF's [CC directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/main/tensorflow_federated/cc) contains the code; most of the implementation is in the [`executors` directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/main/tensorflow_federated/cc/core/impl/executors).

These APIs can certainly be called from C++ code; see, e.g., the implementation of TFF's [RunWorker](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/cc/simulation/servers.cc#L74), which starts and runs a server that can execute TFF computations.

Comment: One note as a comment, since this may change soon. Managing the build relationship between TFF and TF in open source is a little fraught; TFF today [links dynamically against prebuilt TF shared objects](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/main/tensorflow_federated/tools/build_defs.bzl#L60), but this does not work in all cases; TFF tests as much as it can in open source, but some components (like the sequence executor) do not work with this approach. TFF is working on decoupling this aspect of the build.